# pandas: how to create a DataFrame with composite types (arrays, maps, struct)?

Tags: pandas, pyarrow

I want to create a pandas dataframe with STRUCT, MAP and ARRAY data types.

Just now I do it with PyArrow and then convert it to pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

if __name__ == "__main__":

    simple_array = pa.array([1, 2, 3], type=pa.int64())

    struct_type = pa.struct([('name', pa.string()), ("age", pa.int32())],)
    struct_array = pa.array([{"name": "Belzebub", "age": 13}, {"name": "Sathanail", "age": 666},
                             {"name": "Succubus", "age": 1000}], type=struct_type)

    array_array = pa.array([["Chizhick", "Pyzhick"], ["кролики"], ["unique", "discounts", "on", "everythong"]],
                           type=pa.list_(pa.string()))

    map_array = pa.array([
        list({"dick_length": 355.14, "dick_diameter": 91.5}.items()),
        list({"dick_length": 111.4, "dick_diameter": 105}.items()),
        list({"dick_length": np.nan, "dick_diameter": np.nan, "boobs_weight": 1000}.items())
        ], pa.map_(pa.string(), pa.float64())
    )

    uber_table = pa.table([simple_array, struct_array, array_array, map_array],
                          ["simple_col", "struct_col", "array_col", "map_col"])


    df = uber_table.to_pandas()
```

But isnt't there a simple way to create such dataframe directly in Pandas?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the same DataFrame directly in pandas:

```py
df_from_pandas = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "simple_col": [
            1, 2, 3
        ],
        "struct_col": [
            {"name": "Belzebub", "age": 13}, 
            {"name": "Sathanail", "age": 666},
            {"name": "Succubus", "age": 1000}
        ],
        "array_col": [
            ["Chizhick", "Pyzhick"], 
            ["кролики"], 
            ["unique", "discounts", "on", "everythong"]
        ],
        "map_col": [
            list({"dick_length": 355.14, "dick_diameter": 91.5}.items()),
            list({"dick_length": 111.4, "dick_diameter": 105}.items()),
            list({"dick_length": np.nan, "dick_diameter": np.nan, "boobs_weight": 1000}.items())
        ]
    }
)
```